# How to read c++ structure binary file in excel vba

Tags: c++, vba, excel

I have a c++ generated structure file that contains the corresponding struct in binary form:

```
struct userinfo
{
   char username[200];
   char Password[200];
   char Genkey[200];
   long UniqueKey;
};
```

How can I read this file in Excel VBA code?

Answer (score 2):

This should get you somewhere:

```
Option Explicit

Type userinfo
    username As String * 200
    Password As String * 200
    Genkey As String * 200
    UniqueKey As Long
End Type

Sub readbin()
    Dim rec As userinfo
    Dim intFileNum As Integer
    intFileNum = FreeFile
    Open "C:\Temp\my.bin" For Binary Access Read As intFileNum
    Do While Not EOF(intFileNum)
        Get intFileNum, , rec
        Debug.Print "->", rec.UniqueKey, rec.username
        Debug.Print , rec.Password
        Debug.Print , rec.Genkey
    Loop
    Close intFileNum
End Sub
```

---

Further notes: C++ padding is not standardized, and is a pain when interfacing with other languages. The best way to deal with C++ padding is to remove it so it to become language neutral. This can be done by [redefining C++ to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3277953/327026):

```
#pragma pack (push, 1)
struct userinfo
{
   char username[200];
   char Password[200];
   char Genkey[200];
   long UniqueKey;
};
#pragma pack (pop)
```

Although if you can't modify the source program, then you might need to look around for other options.

Comment: Struct padding will make this unreliable.

Comment: Any hints on how to untangle C++ padding rules? At what record is it *not* 604 bytes?