# Is there any way to control the padding between struct members (incl. bit field) in C++?

Tags: c++, c, padding

I'm working on parsing network data stream, I'm wondering if there is any way I can map the data stream directly to the data structure.

For example, I want to define the data structure for an RTP protocol as follows.

```
class RTPHeader
{
   int version:2; // The first two bits is version.
   int P:1;  // The next bits is an field P.
   int X:1;
   int CC:4;
   int M:1;
   int PT:7;
   int sequenceNumber;
   int64 timestamp;
   .....
};
```

And using it this way.

```
RTPHeader header;
memcpy(&header, steamData, sizeof(header));
```

But as the C++ compiler will insert padding between the members, is there any way to control that so that no padding are added between members (including the bit field members)?

This question is NOT a duplicate of [How to get rid of padding bytes between data members of a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277842/how-to-get-rid-of-padding-bytes-between-data-members-of-a-struct) because there can be bit fields in my example.

Comment: I believe there's no standard way to do this but your compiler might have some extension (e.g. VS has it) that allows you to control padding. I hope someone proves me wrong.

Comment: The bitfields add up to a multiple of 8, (unsurprisingly).  If you instruct the compiler to pack the class/struct, you should be OK.

Comment: I don't think padding is added between bitfields, is it? It would kind of defeat the point of bitfields otherwise.

Comment: @JonathanPotter if the bitfields do not add up to a multiple of 8, the compiler is not going to slice up subsequent ints etc. across byte boundaries, so it will pad.

Comment: @MartinJames: right, but not *between* bitfields.

Comment: @JonathanPotter - I hope not!!  My embedded code would explode if the compiler did such a thing.

Comment: @MartinJames and JonathanPotter It seems that padding can be added between bitfields even if they add up to a multiple of 8: http://ideone.com/ipIcjH (but here it's because two consecutive members can't fit in a single U32)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you have no requirement that this code "works" on arbitrary machines - e.g. machines that have restrictions as to what byte boundaries an `int` sits on (typically a 4 byte boundary), then using

```
 #pragma(pack)
```

should work, and it's [supported in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure-Packing-Pragmas.html#Structure-Packing-Pragmas) as well as Microsoft and "Microsoft plug in compatible" compilers (Such as Intel's compiler).

But do note that unaligned access is not supported on all processors, so starting a block with a 16-bit value, followed by a 32-bit `int` is possibly going to cause problems.

I would also use a sized integer for sequencenumber to ensure it's 32-bits in EVERY compiler, and not suddenly 16 or 64 bits.

Note also that the C++ standard does not state anything about the order that the bits are stored in a bitfield - or for that matter if there are gaps between them or not. Although you can expect the bitfields to be stored according to the byte-order (little endian machines start with the lowest bits first, big endian machines start with the highest order bits first), the standard does not state anything in that respect.

Comment: I will mark this post as answer,because it not only answer the question, but also point out the bit field store are not defined in C++ and the little endian issue also. Actually after consider the endian issue, I'd like not to choose this solution to parse stream.

Answer (score 8):

If you're able to use C++11, you can take advantage of the align control implemented with the [`alignof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignof) operator.

If you cannot use a C++11 compiler, there's non-standard alternatives that can help you; in GCC the [`__attribute__(packed)`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Type-Attributes.html), and with MSVC the [`#pragma pack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1.aspx).

If your choice is the GCC variant, the attribute must be placed **at the end** of the struct:

```
class RTPHeader
{
    int version:2; // The first two bits is version.
    int P:1;  // The next bits is an field P.
    int X:1;
    int CC:4;
    int M:1;
    int PT:7;
    int sequenceNumber;
    int64 timestamp;
    .....
} __attribute__((packed)) ; // attribute here!
```

If your choice is the MSVC one, the pragma must be placed **before** the struct:

```
#pragma pack(1) // pragma here!
class RTPHeader
{
    int version:2; // The first two bits is version.
    int P:1;  // The next bits is an field P.
    int X:1;
    int CC:4;
    int M:1;
    int PT:7;
    int sequenceNumber;
    int64 timestamp;
    .....
};
```

If your code must be compiled in both, the only way (without C++11 `alignof` operator) is the conditional compilation:

```
#ifdef MSVC
#pragma pack(1)
#endif
class RTPHeader
{
    int version:2; // The first two bits is version.
    int P:1;  // The next bits is an field P.
    int X:1;
    int CC:4;
    int M:1;
    int PT:7;
    int sequenceNumber;
    int64 timestamp;
    .....
#ifdef GCC
}__attribute__((packed));
#else
};
#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

To avoid an insertion of padded bytes you can use

```
#pragma pack(push,n)   // use n = 1 to have 1 Byte resolution

typedef struct {...}MY_STRUCT;

#pragma pack(pop)
```

This worked fine for me.

Also consider the compiling options for Struct Member Alignment

```
/Zp1
```

But keep in mind that this will have an impact to your whole project.

Comment: Yet this is a platform-dependent compiler extension (even if gcc and VS use the same syntax for it, don't know). And the command line option is definitely VS only.