# C++ Random Access Files

Tags: c++, file-io

its my first time to experiment random access files in C++ however, I've tried it before in Java but I can't get it work in C++. The idea is I a want to create 100 empty records, and then store a record at a particular record number in the file. Here is my code, I kept it as simple as possible.

I have here a structure named Tool:

```
struct Tool {
    int number;
    char name[20];
    int quantity;
    double cost;
};
```

And here is what I have in the main function:

```
fstream outFile;
outFile.open("inventory.dat");

// Create 100 empty tool records
Tool tool;
tool.number = 0;
tool.name[0] = '\0';
tool.quantity = 0;
tool.cost = 0;  

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&tool.number), sizeof(int));
    outFile.write(tool.name, sizeof(char)* 20);
    outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&tool.quantity), sizeof(int));
    outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&tool.cost), sizeof(double));
}

// Insert A tool record
Tool t;
t.number = 3;
t.quantity = 7;
t.cost = 57;
strcpy(tool.name, "Electric Sander");

outFile.seekp((tool.number - 1) * sizeof(Tool));
outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&tool.number), sizeof(int));
outFile.write(tool.name, sizeof(char)* 20);
outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&tool.quantity), sizeof(int));
outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&tool.cost), sizeof(double));

outFile.close();
```

The part where I initialize 100 empty record works fine (assuming we are to comment to the insert section of the code.

However, when the insert section is performed, my program generates 4 GB of data. I'm not sure what's going on. I appreciate any kind of help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not accounting for padding between members.  The `seekp` operation using `sizeof(Tool)`, but the write operation uses the sizes of the individual members.

Comment: Also, you are not using binary mode. That does not seem to be your intent...

Comment: Also you should set the binary mode when you open your file: `outFile.open("inventory.dat", std::ios::binary);`.

Comment: If your code contains `reinterpret_cast` it's wrong, unless you can explain why it's not wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write the entire contents of the struct

```
    outFile.seekp(t.number*sizeof(Tool));
    outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&tool),sizeof(Tool));
```

Don´t forget to tell the compiler to don´t insert the padding

```
#ifdef MSVC
#pragma pack(push,1)
#endif
struct Tool {
    int number;
    char name[20];
    int quantity;
    double cost;
#ifdef GCC
}__attribute__((packed));
#else
};
#endif

#ifdef MSVC
#pragma pack(pop)
#endif
```

Sources:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/26344/writing-reading-data-structure-to-a-file-using-c
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18654265/194717
Comments of our valuable members.

Comment: Note:  This will also write any padding between the members.

Comment: You would want to use your favorite compiler's compiler-specific way of explicitly setting member alignment before doing this to ensure the file format is consistent and predictable.

Comment: Nice edit; note for MSVC (to be equivalent to your GCC attribute) you actually want `#pragma pack(push,1)` before and `#pragma pack(pop)` after, to restore the default alignment. Otherwise it affects *everything* after that line.

Comment: I am ashamed, because I am a C# programmer, just wanted to try to answer a C++ question, that initially seemed simple. Feel free to edit or tell me to remove the 'answer' :)

Comment: Don't worry. "C++" and "simple" don't generally belong in a sentence together.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know I can directly write a struct (like a serialized object).. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You used `tool` where you meant `t` in the last part. In particular:

```
outFile.seekp((tool.number - 1) * sizeof(Tool));
```

Should be:

```
outFile.seekp((t.number - 1) * sizeof(Tool));
```

As well as all the other `tool.` fields at the end (presuming you want to use `t`). `tool.number` at that point is 0, so `tool.number - 1` is -1. If `pos_type` is unsigned and 32-bits, the wrapped value puts your requested position at around 4GB.

Also the alignment point Thomas Matthews brought up in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26899829/c-random-access-files/26899858#comment42352435_26899829) and Tony detailed in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26899874/616460) is important to ensure that the data in the file is correct.

The point Deduplicator and Galik raised in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26899829/c-random-access-files/26899858#comment42352461_26899829) regarding binary mode is also important to ensure that data is written correctly.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I was so messed up coding trying every possible code and forgot to name them appropriately until I gave up and posted the question here. This helped. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative:

```
struct Tool
{
    int number;
    char name[20];
    int quantity;
    double cost;
    void binary_write(std::ostream& out) const
    {
      out.write((char *) &number, sizeof(number));
      out.write((char *) &name[0], sizeof(name);
      out.write((char *) &quantity, sizeof(quantity));
      out.write((char *) &cost, sizeof(cost));
    }
    void binary_read(std::istream& inp)
    {
      inp.read((char *) &number, sizeof(number));
      inp.read((char *) &name[0], sizeof(name);
      inp.read((char *) &quantity, sizeof(quantity));
      inp.read((char *) &cost, sizeof(cost));
    }
    size_t binary_size(void) const
    {
      return sizeof(number) + sizeof(name)
             + sizeof(quantity) + sizeof(cost);
    }
};

int main(void)
{
  std::ofstream outfile("test.dat", ios::binary);
  if (!outfile)
  {
    cerr << "Error opening test.dat\n";
    return 1;
  }
  Tool t;
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
  {
    t.binary_write(outfile);
  }
  outfile.close();
  std::ifstream in_file("test.dat", ios::binary)
  if (!in_file)
  {
    cerr << "Error opening test.dat for reading\n";
    return 2;
  }
  in_file.seekg(10 * t.binary_size(), ios::beg);
  t.binary_read(in_file);
  return 0;
}
```

The concept here is to place the read and write functions into the object, because the object knows about its members and you can hide the data from other objects (a good thing).