# GCC generates wrong structure offset why?

Tags: c, gcc

I have this code:

mbr.h:

```
struct mbr_partition {
                char flags;
                char start_head;
                char start_sector;
                char start_cyl;
                char type;
                char last_head;
                char last_sector;
                char last_cyl;
                uint32_t start;
                uint32_t size;
        };

        struct mbr {
                char bootloader[446];
                struct mbr_partition partition1;
                struct mbr_partition partition2;
                struct mbr_partition partition3;
                struct mbr_partition partition4;
                char magic[2];
        };
```

And: main.c:

```
int main()
{
        printf("%d\n", sizeof(struct mbr));
        printf("%d\n", sizeof(struct mbr_partition));
        printf("%d\n", sizeof(long));
        struct mbr mbr;
        printf("%d, %d\n", ((char *) &mbr.magic) - ((char *) &mbr), sizeof(mbr)$
        printf("1: %d\n", ((char *) &mbr.partition1) - ((char *) &mbr));
        printf("2: %d\n", ((char *) &mbr.partition2) - ((char *) &mbr));
        printf("3: %d\n", ((char *) &mbr.partition3) - ((char *) &mbr));
        printf("4: %d\n", ((char *) &mbr.partition4) - ((char *) &mbr));
        return 0;
}
```

And output:

```
516
16
8
512, 516
1: 448
2: 464
3: 480
4: 496
```

Why size is 516 bytes (It should be 512) ?
Why partition1 offset is 448 not 446?
How can I fix it?

Comment: I think you might have to add attribute called **packed** to the struct to remove extra padding.

Comment: Padding.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18654110/12711

Comment: Does `-Wpadded` help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because there might be some padding bytes or padding bits.

Quoted from N1570 `6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers`:(emphasis mine)

> 15 Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units
>   in which bit-fields reside have addresses that increase in the order
>   in which they are declared. A pointer to a structure object, suitably
>   converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a
>   bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.
>   **There may be unnamed padding within a structure object**, but not at its beginning.