# Pushing data into vector from struct with unpredictable size

Tags: c++

I have an object that writes to a file using classic `fwrite`, `fseek`, and so on. It writes to files using structs, such as

```
fwrite(&my_struct, 1, sizeof(MyStruct_t), fd);
```

I did not write this code but that has been working for ~15 years. I have a requirement to convert this two objects, one that continues to write to a file in this way, and now to write to a vector to avoid the file i/o. So I replaced all `fwrite`, `fread`, etc, with `Write` and `Read` and so on. In the file writing object this simply wraps the file functions, and for the vector object this simply pushes data into the vector or moves a local `vector_position` around to best maintain transparency between the two objects.

However, "writing" (and likely reading) from the vector is not working out as I hoped because of, I suppose, data alignment issues. I'm not even sure if this would be a problem in my OS (vxWorks) because I see all structs have some data alignment macro. But I would like to know if there is a non macro way to go about this.

The issue is that, I naively expected `sizeof m` here to be `5` while it is actually `8` causing me to push garbage into my vector. Is there any way to do this without aligning the struct based on my compiler? I write most of my prototypes in an online environment.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

typedef struct {
    uint32_t a;
    char b;
} myst;

void Write(std::vector<unsigned char> &v, void *data, size_t s){
    unsigned char *bdata = static_cast<unsigned char*>(data);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < s; i++){
        printf("0x%x\n", bdata[i]);
        v.push_back(bdata[i]);  
        // problem - "s" = 8, not 5, so more data is written 
    }
}

int main()
{
    myst m;
    m.a = 0xA1B2C3D4;
    m.b = 0xE5;
    std::vector<unsigned char> s;
    Write(s, &m, sizeof(m));
}
```

Comment: I think this answer might make you understand more: [SO-Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/119128/11023871)
Basically, your integer takes 4 bytes, your char takes 1 byte, but your system will do a padding of 3 bytes to fill the remaining to 8

Comment: Push each item individually.

Comment: But your code with fread and fwrite will have the same issue, so is it really a problem?

Comment: Your question seems to be whether there's a standardised way to pack, avoiding padding, and the answer is there is not (because that's usually implemented as a non-standard `#pragma`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to control the padding between struct members (incl. bit field) in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18653110/is-there-any-way-to-control-the-padding-between-struct-members-incl-bit-field)

Comment: @john You're right. Each struct is currently manually aligned and I suppose I understand the reason for doing this was to make `fread` and `fwrite` easier to use in this context.

Comment: Your struct wastes 3 bytes to alignment, snd so does its byte-for-byte copy to a file, and a byte-for-byte copy to a vector. No big surprise here, and also no harm whatsoever. I recommend leaving this thing alone.

Comment: On a different note,  I don't see any purpose of hex-formatting your bytes. You don't do that when you write to a file. Why do that when writing to a vector? Also you may want to use `std::stream` facilities rather than your homegrown solution, and avoid a bunch of totally unnecessary code duplication.

Answer (score 1):

To force it down to the unpadded size you can use

```
#pragma pack(1)
```

As described in GNU docs in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.4/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html it "simply sets the new alignment" to the value in between parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

In case your struct ends up in an array, sizeof needs to add the extra padding in the end. I don't think there's a way around this.
If your problem is "to push garbage into my vector", my advice is to simply initialize the struct to zero before using it:

```
myst m;
memset(&m, 0, sizeof(m));
m.a = 0xA1B2C3D4;
m.b = 0xE5;
```

This is very common in the embedded space (VxWorks).